# Is there an inverse function for pyspark's expr?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know there's a function called [expr](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=registerjava#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) that turns your spark sql into a spark column with that expression:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
>>> F.expr("length(name)")
Column<b'length(name)'>
```

Is there a function that does the opposite - turn your Column into a pyspark's sql string? Something like:

```
>>> F.inverse_expr(F.length(F.col('name')))
'length(name)'
```

I found out that Column's `__repr__` gives you an idea what the column expression is (like `Column<b'length(name)'>`, but it doesn't seem to be usable programmatically, without some hacky parsing and string-replacing.

Comment: Can you please specify the motive of converting column to sql expression?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I'm building a tool that enables analysts to write some spark queries - these are stored in spark sql. However writing the sql directly in string isn't great - there's no syntax checking. So it would be better for them to write pyspark code and then convert it to sql.

Comment: There are a lot of functions only available in Spark SQL. If you want to use one of these functions on a column, you will need to express the column as Spark SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, we can use `column#expr` to get sql type expression as below-

```scala
length($"entities").expr.toString()
// length('entities)
```

In pyspark-

```py
print(F.length("name")._jc.expr.container)
# length(name)
```

Comment: For some functions, I get all uppercase strings like `F.signum` gives me `SIGNUM`. But since pyspark sql is case insensitive, all good!

Comment: Seems lambda functions are not formatted correctly in Spark 3.2.1:  
```pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'lambdafunction'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer by @Som in Spark 2.4.2 and Spark 3.2.1 and it didn't work.
The following approach worked for me in pyspark:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import Column

def inverse_expr(c: Column) -> str:
    """Convert a column from `Column` type to an equivalent SQL column expression (string)"""
    from packaging import version
    sql_expression = c._jc.expr().sql()
    if version.parse(pyspark.__version__) < version.parse('3.2.0'):
        # prior to Spark 3.2.0 f.col('a.b') would be converted to `a.b` instead of the correct `a`.`b`
        # this workaround is used to fix this issue
        sql_expression = re.sub(
            r'''(`[^"'\s]+\.[^"'\s]+?`)''',
            lambda x: x.group(0).replace('.', '`.`'),
            sql_expression,
            flags=re.MULTILINE
        )
    return sql_expression
```

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> inverse_expr(F.length(F.col('name')))
'length(`name`)'
>>> inverse_expr(F.length(F.lit('name')))
"length('name')"
>>> inverse_expr(F.length(F.col('table.name')))
'length(`table`.`name`)'
```